# Unable to apply UIBezierPath in CellForRowAtIndexPath before scroling the TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Using This code I got My Profile Picture in Proper D shape but after When  i scrolling the  tableView not when we are entering  in to view controller.

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cellimg.boundsbyRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomRight|UIRectCornerTopRight)cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame =cellimg.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
cellimg.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: `[yourTableView reloadData]` .... add this line in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: please edit the question's title

Comment: hi.. M Zubair Shamshad its not working for me.. still  profile picture makes in d shape when we scrolling t he table view .. profile pictures is coming from web Service.  m writing this code in CellForRowAtIndex.. any other solution please...thanku

Comment: i have found the solution..just have to write this code in main thread  in one line..            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                         // write Code here                                                                                        });                   Thanks:;

Answer (score 0):

Use D shape mask image with below code it may be work for you

CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];

mask.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@“your_D_ShapeMask.png"].CGImage;

mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

[cellimg.layer setMask:mask];